# Deploying Meteor with PhusionPassenger: node not found in $PATH

Tags: nginx, meteor, deployment, passenger

I am deploying an application made with Meteor 1.8 on a server running Ubuntu 16.04. I have been following the tutorial [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/nginx/oss/stretch/deploy_app.html) to use Phusion Passenger to deploy the app in association with Nginx.

However, the way I have installed Node.js is different from the way described in the tutorial, and this leads to an error. As a result, I need to change the `$PATH` environment variable to tell Passenger where to find node.

——— DETAILS (can be skipped) ———

I have installed Node 8.16.2 using NVM. I have a non-root user named `meteor` to run the app process. When logged in to the server as `meteor`, the command `which node` returns:

```
/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/node
```

However, when I connect to the subdomain where the meteor app should be served, an error is logged claiming **node: not found**:

```
App 32461 output: /bin/sh: 1: exec: node: not found
```

To get more information on the problem, I added the following line to the nginx conf file that defines the subdomain:

```
passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
```

My nginx conf file now looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/example/bundle/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    # Tell your app where MongoDB is
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/gizmo;
    # Tell your app what its root URL is
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://example.com;

    ### DEBUGGING ONLY ! REMOVE FOR PRODUCTION ###
    passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
}
```

Now, Phusion Passenger gives me a helpful error page. This has a **Detailed diagnostics** tab, and a **Subprocess** sub-tab. Under this, in the **Environment variables** section, I can see that how `$PATH` is defined:

`PATH=/home/meteor/bin:/home/meteor/.local/bin:/usr/local/gradle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

In other words, it has no knowledge of `/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/node`.

———— DESIRED SOLUTION ————

The best solution seems to be to add the path to node to `$PATH`. The [PhusionPassenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html#nginx) suggest editing `/etc/default/nginx`. I added the following line to this file:

```
export PATH=/home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/:$PATH
```

But this has no effect.

———— STOPGAP SOLUTION ————

My stopgap solution has been to create the director `/home/meteor/bin/` and to create a symbolic link to the node app:

```
sudo mkdir /home/meteor/bin
sudo ln -s /home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/node /home/meteor/bin
sudo chown -R meteor: /home/meteor/bin
```

This works, but I would like to understand how to get Nginx and PhusionPassenger to use the correct `$PATH` in the environment variables.

Comment: Can you please also provide the path to the binary using `whereis` (read the [difference](https://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences)). Actually installing node using NVM may result it to be in a different path than using deb source for example.

Comment: `whereis node` =>
`node: /home/meteor/bin/node /home/meteor/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/node`  (The first path is the symbolic link to the second path.)